# Doctrine 2: OneToMany relation

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

```
/** @Entity */  
class First
{
    /** @OneToMany(targetEntity="Second", mappedBy="parent") */
    protected $secondList;

    // access methods here
    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->secondList = new ArrayCollection();
    } 
}

/** @Entity */
class Second 
{
    /** 
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="First", inversedBy="secondList")
     * @JoinColumn(name="First_id", referencedColumnName="Id")
     */
    protected $parent;
}
```

Here is the problem with taking into `ArrayCollection $secondList` elements from `Second` class. `Second` ManyToOne relation is working properly. Perhaps I did something wrong in initializing a persistance (because `First_Id` in SQL base is `null` always).

```
$first = new Second();
$second = new First();
$first->getSecond()->add($second);
$em->persist($second);
$em->persist($first);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Doctrine2 docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#establishing-associations) say this:

```
In the case of bi-directional associations you have to update the fields on both sides:
```

This means that you'll have to do something like:

```
$second->setParent($first);
```

As `$second` **table** has the foreign key. 
Or you could add a `cascade={"persist"}` option to the`$first->secondList` property.

Comment: Ok, that's really help me in setting First_Id column in Second table records. However, trying to fetching First class object doesn't taking Second's to `ArrayCollection`. I have empty collection only :|

Comment: so in the db everything is ok? How are you fetching the stuff? and how are you checking what you have? Because when you call $first->getSecond() it should load it.

Comment: And indeed that's what im doing. DB is ok (eventually schema was created by doctrine tool-kit). I gets the objects using find() or getRepository() methods from `EntityManager` class. Objects was created properly, even i get only `Second` class objects i have full relation with `First` related class object. Oh and i checking that list by using `serialize($first->getSecondList()->current())`, coz taking stuff by `$takedSecond->getSomeOtherValue()` shows error within using method on non-object variable.

Comment: I'm not sure that current() triggers a load. So try putting the list in a foreach, or using the array syntax. So if $list = $first->getSecondList(), try dumping $list[0].

Comment: Great, its working. Thanks a lot! Problem was in that the `ArrayCollection::current()` method is not triggering load.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure you close your parenthesis in the First class.

```
/** @OneToMany(targetEntity =  "Second", mappedBy = "parent" ) */
```

If that is not the problem - is there any error message ?

Comment: Oh, typho. There is no error message, but if i try to persist First class object before Second there is error about using cascade mapping (some attribute, i havent found that in doctrine references about neccessary using).

Comment: Try to add this to your OneToMany relationship (for the cascade bug): `cascade={"persist"}` I am not exactly sure what is the other problem... Is everything saved into the database?